# Transform Weierstrass equation into cubic

Tags: elliptic-curves

How can I transform an elliptic curve over the real numbers in Weierstrass form

$y^2=x^3+ax+b$

into a cubic of the form

$y^2=x(x-c)(x-d)$?

Comment: Put another way, a pure translation in $x$ to move a real root (there is one) from where it is to $0.$

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477834/making-an-elliptic-curve-out-of-a-cubic-polynomial-made-a-cube-or-ax3bx2cx.