# Sums of three cubes in arithmetic progression equal to a cube $x^3+(x+y)^3+(x+2y)^3 = z^3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, computational-mathematics

Using exhaustive search, small ***positive and primitive*** integer solutions to,

$$x^3+(x+y)^3+(x+2y)^3 = 3 x^3 + 9 x^2 y + 15 x y^2 + 9 y^3= z^3\tag1$$

are,

$$x,y = 3,1,\quad x+y =2^2$$

$$x,y = 149,107,\quad x+y =2^8$$

$$x,y = 317,808,\quad x+y =3^2\cdot 5^3$$

**P.S.** The equation,

$$ax^3 +bx^2 y + c x y^2 + d y^3= z^3$$

with initial rational solution $x_0, y_0$ can be transformed into an *elliptic curve*. Hence $(1)$ has an infinite number of primitive integer solutions. (*Edit*: I just recalled I asked something similar two years ago, but without the *positivity* requirement. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477834/).)

> **Question 1: What are the others with six digits or less?**

$\color{brown}{Update:}$ Zander found,

$$x,y = 243800,249239,\quad x+y =79^3$$

> **Question 2: Why does $x+y$ have interesting factorizations?**

For non-positive $x,y$ we have,

$$x,y = −1839,1871,\quad x+y =2^5$$

$$x,y = 13898941449153,-12222218425537 ,\quad x+y =2^8\cdot1871^3$$

Comment: If you choose $x-y,\,x,\,x+y$ instead, we get a simpler equation $3x^3 + 6xy^2 = z^3$. Since $z^3$ must be a multiple of 3, we can set $z=3m$ to turn it into $x^3 + 2xy^2 = 9m^3$. From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html it seems there is no general solutions like the Pythagoras triples?

Comment: I have evaluated the table in http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/eslp/tables.htm and only got OP's 3 pairs. @Tito With $x-y,x,x+y$ we also require $0<y<x$. The two forms are equivalent so it should take the same number of brute-force entries.

Comment: @kennytm: You know about Jarek's tables? I know it has $z<10^6$, and you found there's nothing other than the 3 pairs? Hm, curious.

Comment: Here's one: $x=243800, y=249239$. Found with nearly-brute-force search.

Comment: @kennytm: Why did your code miss Zander's solution?

Comment: @Zander: Thanks! Can you upgrade your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: As to the second question: Well, $x+y$ has to divide $z^3/3$, as by @kennytm's first comment (where it's $x$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1.**

Denote $s=x+y$. Then consider equation
$$
(s-y)^3+s^3+(s+y)^3=z^3,\tag{1}
$$
for positive $s,y,z$. First, consider any such integer solutions: for $s>y$ and for $s<y$.

Eq. $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
3s^3+6sy^2=z^3.\tag{2}
$$ 
Denote $z=3c$, then $(2)$ is equivalent to

$$
s^3+2sy^2=9c^3.\tag{3}
$$

To check all up-to-6-digital $x,y$ (or $s,y$), one can use ineq. $s^3<9c^3$, and consider $c<10^7/\sqrt[3]{9}$, i.e. $c<480750$.

Exhaustive search (up to $c<1\,000\,000$) gives us this table of solutions:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & y & s=x+y & z\\
\hline 
-1 &2 &1 &3\cdot 1 \\ 
\bf{+3} &\bf{1} &\bf{2^2} &\bf{3\cdot 2} \\
-10 &11 &1 &3\cdot 3 \\
-16 &25 &3^2 &3\cdot 11 \\
\bf{+149} &\bf{107} &\bf{2^8} &\bf{3\cdot 136} \\
-919 &955 &6^2 &3\cdot 194 \\
-1839 &1871 &2^5 &3\cdot 292 \\
-8545 &8549 &2^2 &3\cdot 402 \\
+\bf{317} &\bf{808} &\bf{3^2\cdot5^3} &\bf{3\cdot 685} \\
-12759 &14956 &13^3 &3\cdot 4797 \\
-11589 &54181 &2^5\cdot11^3 &3\cdot 33132 \\
-560239 &590614 &3^5\cdot5^3 &3\cdot 133095 \\
\bf{+243800} &\bf{249239} &\bf{79^3} &\bf{3\cdot 271997} \\
\hline
\end{array}
Other solutions have $x+y>10^6$ (even $x+y>2\cdot 10^6$).

**On Question 2.**

Denote 
$$
a=18\frac{c}{s}=6\frac{z}{s},\qquad b=36\frac{y}{s},\tag{4}
$$
then eq. $(3)$ is equivalent to
$$
b^2=a^3-3\times 6^3\tag{5}
$$

"Walking" on rational points of [Elliptic Curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCurve.html) described by eq. $(5)$, one can find more primitive solutions of $(1)$ (with $x>0$ too).  And I guess they cover all such solutions...

**Note** that all $s=x+y$ has one of $4$ forms here (why?):
$$
s=q^3,\quad s=4q^3, \quad s=9q^3, \quad s=36q^3.\tag{6} 
$$
This form is true for $s>y$ and for $s<y$.

Here is table with **positive** primitive $x,y$ (sorted by $s$):

\begin{array}{|r|r|rl|}
\hline 
x & y & s=x+y & \\
\hline
3 &1 &4&=4\cdot 1^3 \\
149 &107 &256&=4(2^2)^3 \\
317 &808 &1125&=9\cdot 5^3 \\
243800 &249239 &493039&=79^3 \\
4062853 &437147 &4500000&=36(2 \cdot 5^2)^3 \\
720469 &11105855 &11826324&=36(3\cdot 23)^3 \\
2957658 &181262351 &184220009&=569^3 \\
87092698624 &2477541935 &89570240559&=9(3^2\cdot 239)^3 \\
456326994059 &722215431505 &1178542425564&=36(7\cdot 457)^3 \\
3170389673427 &431591782862 &3601981456289&=15329^3 \\
10460723603247633 &5072768120572198 &15533491723819831&=(59\cdot4229)^3 \\
132098636066470851 &28361108004240976 &160459744070711827&=(7\cdot 149\cdot 521)^3 \\
74556823768778731 &160637266326925333 &235194090095704064&=4(2^3\cdot 13\cdot 3739)^3 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive data! (I factorized the $s$ column of your first table.) I hope you don't mind.