# Why is $y^2 = 1+x^4$ an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I saw in [a document](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/papers_pdf/CM_minnesota2010_print.pdf)  that $y^2 = 1+x^4$ is (the affine equation of) an elliptic curve. Why is it the case? Typically, SAGE tells me it is isomorphic to $y^2 = x^3 - 4x$, which is an elliptic curve with Weierstrass equation, but I don't know how to prove this.

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, $y^2=1-x^4$ is also an elliptic curve… Do all equations like $y^2 = $ quartic, give elliptic curves?

Comment: I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591990, but we have to be careful about  isomorphic/birationally equivalent/isogenous...

Comment: What definition are you using for isomorphism of curves?

Comment: Another example is the elliptic curve $u^3+v^3=w^3$ being $y^2=x^3-432$ via $x=12w/(u+v), y = 36(u-v)/(u+v)$, given p. 53 in Alf van der Poorten's book on Fermat Last theorem.

Comment: In general, I think that if $y^2 = f(x)$ is an affine model of a smooth projective curve $C$, then the genus of the hyperelliptic curve $C$ is $g$, where the degree of $f$ is $2g+1$ or $2g+2$ (see 1st § of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_curve)

Comment: My comment from Sep 17 at 15:16 is also on page 18 of Silverman–Tate.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477834/making-an-elliptic-curve-out-of-a-cubic-polynomial-made-a-cube-or-ax3bx2cx

Comment: As I mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964300/nonsingular-projective-curve-model-corresponding-to-y2-x41), the projective closure of $y^2=x^4+1$ in $\Bbb P^2$ is singular (the point at infinity [0:1:0] is a singularity). However, there exists a unique (up to isomorphism) smooth projective curve $C$ such that $k(C) \cong k(x)[y]/(y^2 - x^4 - 1)$, which can be given by a "weighted projective hyperelliptic equation" (Definition 10.1.10. in Galbraith's book on PKC) — it has two points at infinity, and $C$ has genus $1$. See also exercise II.2.14 in Silverman's book "AEC".

Comment: The question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239746/birationally-transforming-a-quartic-elliptic-curve?rq=1 might be relevant as well.

Comment: The SAGE commands were : x, y = polygen(QQ, 'x, y')
Jacobian(y^2 - (1 + x^4))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A very concrete answer to your question can be found in Exercise 1.15 on page 31 of Silverman and Tate's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* (2nd Edition).

You ask in a comment to your question:

> Do all equations of the form $y^2 = \text{quartic}$ give elliptic curves?

The answer is clearly no, since for example the curve $y^2 = x^4$ has a singularity at the origin. Nevertheless, if you add the assumption that the quartic has no repeated roots then the answer is yes, as has already been mentioned in another answer.

In particular, the content of the exercise mentioned above says that if $g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ is a quartic polynomial, if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $g(t)$, and if $\beta \neq 0$ is any number, then the equations
\begin{align*}
x = \frac{\beta}{t - \alpha} \quad \text{and} \quad y = x^2 u = \frac{\beta^2 u}{(t - \alpha)^2}
\end{align*}

give a birational transformation $\phi: \mathcal{Q} \dashrightarrow \mathcal{E}$ between the curve $\mathcal{Q}: u^2 = g(t)$ and the curve $\mathcal{E}: y^2 = f(x)$, where
\begin{align*}
\phi: \mathcal{Q} &\dashrightarrow \mathcal{E}\\
(t, u) &\mapsto (x, y) = \left(\frac{\beta}{t - \alpha}, \frac{\beta^2 u}{(t - \alpha)^2} \right)
\end{align*}

and $$f(x) = g'(\alpha) \beta x^3 + \dfrac{g''(\alpha)}{2!} \beta^2 x^2 + \dfrac{g'''(\alpha)}{3!} \beta^3 x + \dfrac{g^{''''}(\alpha)}{4!} \beta^4$$

is cubic. Moreover, the exercise asks to show that if all the complex roots of $g(t)$ are different, then also the roots of $f(x)$ are distinct, and hence that $\mathcal{Q}: u^2 = g(t)$ is an elliptic curve.

---

> **An Example**

For instance we can apply this to the curve $u^2 = 1 - t^4$ (the roots of $1 - t^4$ are slightly easier to work with than the roots of $1 + t^4$). In this case $g(t)= 1 - t^4$ has as roots the fourth roots of unity $\pm 1, \pm i$. If we choose $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = -\dfrac{1}{4}$, then the transformation 
\begin{align*}
x = -\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{t - 1} \quad \text{and} \quad y = \frac{1}{16} \frac{u}{(t - 1)^2}
\end{align*}

gives a birational transformation with the curve
$$
y^2 = f(x) = x^3 - \frac{3}{8}x^2 + \frac{1}{16} x - \frac{1}{256},
$$

which is already in Weierstrass form. Moreover, if you want you can depress the cubic by making the change $x \mapsto X - \dfrac{1}{3}\left( -\dfrac{3}{8} \right) = X + \dfrac{1}{8}$ and $y \mapsto Y$, which gives you the equation
$$
Y^2 = X^3 + \frac{1}{64} X.
$$

Comment: Just to be sure: $(uv)^2 = v^4 - t^4$ defines a singular quartic in $\Bbb P^2$, which is birationally equivalent to $y^2z = x^3 + xz^2/64$ over $\Bbb Q$. Is it correct? However, the latter is a smooth cubic curve and can't be _isomorphic_ to the former, right? Thank you!

Comment: Should I ask a new question to get an answer to my above comment? I think it is strongly related to your nice post, so that you may be able to answer it ;-). Many thanks !

Comment: (When I wrote "quartic" above, it means that the degree of the projective variety is $4$, as in p. 52 Hartshorne)

Comment: Hi, my problem with this approach is that you need a root $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ so that $g(\alpha)=0$.  This means you have to switch computation from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb C$ or at least to some algebraic number field. Isn't there a way which does not require a root of $g$? For example just knowledge of some point $P$ such that $g(x_P) = y_P^2$ is not enough?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I have the same question. Have you got any answer?

Answer (score 6):

To me, an elliptic curve over a field $k$ is a (projective, non-singular)
genus one curve defined over $k$ with a specified point $O$, also defined
over $k$, to serve as an identity in its group. The Weierstrass curve
$y^2=x^3+ax+b$ is, if non-singular, an (affine model of an)
elliptic curve with the point at infinity the point $O$.

In general, a curve $y^2=f(x)$ with $f$ a quartic having no repeated zeros
is an affine model of a non-singular genus one curve. (It will have two
points "at infinity"). Is it an elliptic curve? I'd say no, until one chooses
a $O$ point. To do that over the field $k$, either one needs to pick
a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the curve with $x_0$, $y_0\in k$ or one must
pick a point at infinity at zero. But the points at infinity are defined
over $k$ iff $a$ is a square in $k$ where $f(x)=ax^4+\cdots$.

In your examples, $y^2=x^4+1$ is an elliptic curve, where you can choose
a point at infinity or $(0,1)$ as $O$. Also $y^2=1-x^4$ is, again choosing
$O=(0,1)$ but over $\Bbb Q$, the points at infinity are not defined
over $\Bbb Q$.

[I'm assuming $k$ is not of characteristic $2$ throughout.]

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain (or give a precise reference) why a curve $y^2=f(x)$ with $f$ a quartic having no repeated zeros, gives has _genus one_ ?

Comment: Apply the Riemann-Hurwitz formula for the genus to the map $E\to\Bbb P^1$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x$. @Alphonse

Comment: Shouldn't we get that the genus is $g=3$, from the [genus-degree formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula), the degree being $d=4$?

Comment: No, it's not a non-singular quartic. @Alphonse

Comment: What is wrong when I applied the genus-degree formula?

Comment: @Alphonse As I said, it's not a non-singular quartic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_curve

Comment: Ok thank you. So $y^2=1+x^4$ happens to be a smooth cubic plane curve, actually, right? Moreover, would you know how to prove it's isomorphic (or birational) to $y^2=x^3-4x$ as I asked?

Comment: $y^2=x^4+1$ is a double cover of $\Bbb P^1$ ramified at the primitive eight roots of unity. $y^2=x^3-4x$ is a double cover of $\Bbb P^1$ ramified at $0$, $\pm 2$ and $\infty$. They'll be isomorphic over $\Bbb C$ if the cross-ratios of these quartets of points are the same. But, I'd trust SAGE on this one; this is very much the sort of maths it was invented for.

Comment: OK, thank you. I think I will accept this answer if nobody provides another approach. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer, at least:
$$y^2=(1-x^2)(1-k^2 x^2)$$
is the elliptic curve associated with the [Jacobi elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) $\operatorname{sn}(\cdot,k)$. For $k=i$, you get $y^2=1-x^4$ (see [lemniscatic elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscatic_elliptic_function)). And $1+x^4$ is the same thing as $1-x^4$, up to rotating the complex $x$ plane 45 degrees.