# genus of $y^2＝1＋x^4$

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I heard $E:y^2＝1＋x^4$ is Elliptic curve because it is birational to $y^2＝x^3-4x$.
But I have a question.

The projective closure of $E$ is $Y^2Z^2＝Z^4＋X^4$, and this is smooth curve（if it is not smooth, then the curve is not elliptic curve）, so its genus is
$（4-1）（4-2）/2＝3$.
But elliptic curve has genus 1.
Where am I missing?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901532/why-is-y2-1x4-an-elliptic-curve), with the comments about the genus. "As I said, it's not a non-singular quartic."

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but then, this is hyper elliptic curve but not elliptic curve?  what is the genus of $E$?

Comment: An alternative approach to using that birational model explicitly: The curve $E$ is NOT smooth at its point at infinity $(0:1:0)$. If one blows it up there, one will get that the genus (of the smooth model) is $1$ (char 0) - e.g., use Riemann-Hurwitz, or calculate the space of regular differentials - exercises  well worth doing...

Comment: Before blowing up, the curve's genus is 3, right?

Comment: Sorry I just deleted a comment, as I misread yours.

Comment: According to the  (the inadequate) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula the arithmetic genus is indeed  $3$. After blowing up so that one a smooth curve, the arithmetic and geometric genus (genera!) coincide. If we can end up with an ell. curve (ok, after choosing a base point), that common number has to be one.

Comment: @peterag It is maybe not completely clear from your comments that the for the OPs curve the geometric and arithmetic genera *do not* conincide since it is not smooth

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I certainly had been trying to convey that idea...

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Yes, I also wanted to write "elliptic curve". So I have deleted the old comment. Still, the answer by Angina Seng certainly is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion comes from the fact that you've heard the definition of an elliptic curve require $E$ to be smooth. In fact, it's often convenient to allow $E$ to be singular, but asserting that the base point $O$ is nonsingular.

From the genus degree formula you are getting the wrong answer because $C$ is singular - and the formula only holds for smooth plane curves. You assert your curve is smooth but this is not the case - on the affine patch $y = 1$ we have $f(x,z) = z^2 - x^4 - z^4$ which has vanishing first partial deriviatives at $(0,0)$, hence $C$ is not smooth at the point at infinity.

To put $E$ in Weierstrass form it is suggested in the comments that you can blowup the singular point (at infinity). However in the spirit of Silverman Chapter III, let's just think about what $x$ and $y$ "are" in a Weierstrass equation, and follow the proof that one must exist.

You have your special point $O$, and $\{1,x'\}$ is a basis for $L(2O)$ and $\{1,x',y'\}$ is a basis for $L(3O)$ - then $x'$ and $y'$ will satisfy some Weierstrass equation. So one should just go out and find $x'$ and $y'$ in the wild.

In our case, if we take $O = (0,1)$ we can just take $x' = \frac{y + 1}{x^2}$ and $y' = \frac{y + 1}{x^3}$. Now $L(6O)$ is overloaded with stuff - namely $1, x', y', (x')^2, (y')^2, x'y',(x')^3$, so we just do linear algebra looking for a relation amongst these, one sees that
$$2(y')^2 + x'^3 - x' = 0$$
modulo the equation for your curve. Replacing $x'' = -2x'$ and $y'' = 2y'$ we see that
$$(y'')^2 = (x'')^3 - 4x''$$
and we have our Weierstrass equation.

Comment: Actually, <cough> I had not been suggesting  blowing up the orig. curve to get a model in Weierstrass form. Rather, I was suggesting doing so as a means to see that the (geometric) genus of a/the desingularization was 1. Likewise, it is "a" way of getting the genus of an hyp. ell. curve, and to see what the reg. diff'ls are.