# Isomorphism between $2y^2=x^4-17$ and $y^2=x^3+17x$ over quadratic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Isomorphism between $2y^2=x^4-17$ and $y^2=x^3+17x$ over quadratic field.

I heard $2y^2=x^4-17$ and $y^2=x^3+17x$ are isomorphic curves over a certain quadratic number field (what we call twist).

Over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$, both are elliptic curves. I want to construct an isomorphism between them. How can I do that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may find this post helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901532/why-is-y2-1x4-an-elliptic-curve