# Bringing an elliptic curve over some finite field in Weierstrass form

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I have given the following elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_9 = \mathbb{F}_3[\zeta_8]$ (where $\min_{\mathbb{F}_3}(\zeta_8) = x^2 - x - 1$):

$$
E/\mathbb{F}_9: y^2 = \zeta_8 x^3 + x.
$$
Now I would like to know how to bring this equation in Weierstrass form, i.e. in the form $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ for some $A,B \in \mathbb{F}_9$. I thought about doing a substitution $y = \zeta_{16} y'$ for some element $\zeta_{16}$ with $\zeta_{16}^2 = \zeta_8$, so I could divide by $\zeta_8$ on both sides. However, I don't think that $\zeta_{16}$ is in $\mathbb{F}_9$.

Could you please help me here?

Comment: In characteristics two or three we cannot always bring an elliptic curve into the *short* Weierstrass form. Observe that you are in characteristic three, so it is not necessarily possible to depress the cubic.This time it works like charm though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\zeta = \zeta_8$. Multiplying both sides of $y^2 = \zeta x^3 + x$ by $\zeta^2$ yields
$$
(\zeta y)^2 = \zeta^2 y^2 = \zeta^3 x^3 + \zeta^2 x = (\zeta x)^3 + \zeta (\zeta x) \, .
$$
Letting $\tilde{x} = \zeta x$ and $\tilde{y} = \zeta y$, then
$$
\tilde{y}^2 = \tilde{x}^3 + \zeta \tilde{x} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you! Is there an instructive or intuitive way of seeing how to choose the substitutions as you did? Or is that mere trial and error?

Comment: @Ribbity The only change of variables preserving a short Weierstrass equation is $x = u^2 x'$ and $y = u^3 y'$ for some $u \in \overline{k}$, where $k$ is the base field. (Cf., Silverman's AEC, III.1.) The equation you gave was almost already in short Weierstrass form, so I figured a scaling would work, and I just needed to "absorb" the $\zeta$ into the $x$ variable. In general one can use Nagell's algorithm to put a cubic plane curve in Weierstrass form---see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295620) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477834) for more.